# TypeError: _axios.default.get.mockResolvedValueOnce is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-testing

I'm trying to write a test using React-lIbraries and Jest.

The test should render a mock axios that produces the mock data I've interested but I keep having the following error:

TypeError: _axios.default.get.mockResolvedValueOnce is not a function

Below is my test code:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Home from '../pages/index'


afterEach(cleanup)


const response = [...
]
test('Should render a list of items', async () => {
  axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: response })

  render(
      <Home />
  )
  await waitFor(() => expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalled())

  response.forEach(item => {
    const element = screen.getByText(products.title)
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Comment: Did you try to mock `axios`?